# React app not re-rendering after infinite scroll implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, rerender, react-infinite-scroll-component

Hi guys hoping someone can help me with an issue. I built a function that fetches user posts from backend and returns them as a response:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

const newsFeed = async () => {
await axios
  .post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/news-feed`)
  .then((res) => {
    setPosts(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

This function gets called by `useEffect` and also whenever a post is submitted, liked, commented on etc. so that users' posts are always re-rendered every time they are modified or added.

It was working fine until I decided to implement `Infinite Scroll` to my application. I installed the npm package `react-infinite-scroll-component` and modified my function to look like this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

const newsFeed = async () => {
await axios
  .post(
    `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/news-feed/${page}`)
  .then((res) => {
    let newPosts = posts;
    newPosts = newPosts.concat(res.data);
    setPosts(newPosts);
    setPage(page + 1);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

The infinite scroll is working just fine but now the posts are not being re-rendered every time this function gets called and instead I need to refresh the page to see changes. I tried resetting the state of `page` back to 1 again on my `postSubmit`/`likeHandler` functions but this didn't have any effect. I'm not seeing any errors in the console so am unsure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `let newPosts = posts;` with `let newPosts = [...posts];` Passing the same array reference to `setState` will not cause an update, since the value hasn't changed. By using `[...posts]`, you are creating a new array, causing the component to update.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, that makes sense although I just tried it and nothing changed. Still need to refresh the page to see updates...